# Mathmode with normal font

Tags: math-mode, fonts

is there a way to write everything, even math symbols, in normal font?
I know you can write text in \text{Normal font}, but I dont know how to do the same with math symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\text{Give me normal font}\, and \,not \,this\, one\, please\,  x \in \mathbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```